# RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey or Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey always return null in my VS2019 application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, registry, registrykey

I am trying to validate the registry keys my WinForms app with VS2019(.Net 4.7.2).
I have tried all the solutions out there(but nothing worked) for the same issue such as,

**(a). Setting the Application build to AnyCPU/x64/x86**

**(b). Unchecking the Prefe 32-bit checkbox.**

**(c). Running my VS as an Admin.**

**(d). Checked the permissions of the key and its accessible to Everyone with Full Control enabled.**

```
string var1 = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
using(RegistryKey localMachine = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64) : Registry.LocalMachine) {

  var key = localMachine.OpenSubKey("Computer\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE");
}

using(RegistryKey registry = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey("Computer\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")) {

}
using(RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Computer\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")) {
  if (key != null) {
    
  }
}
```

Tried all the variations to read the directory, but not working.

Is it because of the Domain and Username? Environment.UserDomainName gives my company Domain and  Environment.UserName gives the username I logged into my computer.

Can some one help me what or where I need to change to get the keys?

[image]